# Python: Run a function of each n-th element of the lists contained in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

In Python, we have a list of list. For example:

```
a1 = [[1,4,3,5,6],[6,7,5,3,12],[1,6,4,1,2],[1,9,4,2,1]]
```

or

```
a2 = [[4,3,5,6],[6,7,5,12],[1,6,4,2],[1,9,2,1],[3,2,5,11]]
```

Both the length of `a` and the length of inside lists may vary. But all inside list always have the same length.

I'd like to apply some function to all lists made of the n-th element of each list.

Considering `a2` for example, I'd like to apply iteratively a function to the list [4,6,1,1,3] (list of first elements), then to the list [3,7,6,9,2] (list of the second elements), etc…

the idea resemble to the function:

```
map(a2, my_function)
```

Except that my_function should not be applied to each inside list but to each list of n-th elements.

Hope that makes sense!

**What is most pythonic way for performing such thing?**

Comment: How about nesting map in a lambda? `map(lambda x : map(dostuff, x), your_list)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) with [`*` operator](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
>>> a1 = [[1,4,3,5,6],[6,7,5,3,12],[1,6,4,1,2],[1,9,4,2,1]]
>>> a2 = [[4,3,5,6],[6,7,5,12],[1,6,4,2],[1,9,2,1],[3,2,5,11]]

>>> zip(*a1)
[(1, 6, 1, 1), (4, 7, 6, 9), (3, 5, 4, 4), (5, 3, 1, 2), (6, 12, 2, 1)]
>>> zip(*a2)
[(4, 6, 1, 1, 3), (3, 7, 6, 9, 2), (5, 5, 4, 2, 5), (6, 12, 2, 1, 11)]

>>> map(sum, zip(*a1)) # [1+6+1+1, 4+7+6+9, ...]
[9, 26, 16, 11, 21]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please give a word about how does the * operator as to be interpreted in its use in the function zip?

Comment: @Remi.b, `zip(*[[1,2], [3,4]])` is equivalent to `zip([1,2], [3,4])`. `*` is not specific to the `zip` function. If you follow the link in the answer, there's more kind explanation.

Comment: I didn't realize you added links. Thank you!