# Given a dictionary of lists, is there a pythonic smart way of comparing the i-th element of each list and extract the maximum value?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary like the following:

```
{
'k0': [10, 35, 20],
'k1': [2, 0, 40],
'k2': [21, 400, 5],
}
```

I want to obtain a list with the maximum values in each i-th position of the list. For instance, in this case:

```
max_val_list = [21, 400, 40]
```

Current way of doing it (which seems too messy to me): 
 1. Extract the lists:

```
    k0_list = dicc_name[k0]
    k1_list = dicc_name[k1]
    k2_list = dicc_name[k2]
```

2. Find the max:

```py
    for i, item in enumerate(k0_list):
         max_val_list.append(max([item, k1_list[i], k2_list[i]]))
```

I am sure there must be a way to do it in an elegant way directly from the dictionary and I would like to learn.

Comment: Your example is rather confusing as the results are both "the max in each i-th position" (column-wise) AND the max of each of the lists (row-wise).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I will change that - it is just dummy values, but you are right it might be misleading

Comment: I guess it depends on your set-up, but why not use a list of lists instead of a dict? It seems like it suits your data structure more as the keys are positional

Comment: @Tomerikoo I did not consider this option - I might test it, and then could use the answer from 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811204/python-run-a-function-of-each-n-th-element-of-the-lists-contained-in-a-list

Comment: @jotNewie exactly. Do note that it is the same as Thierry proposed in his answer, just a different way of getting the list (instead of doing `*data.values()` you could simply do `*data`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can `zip` the values of the dict, and get the max of each column:

```
data = {
'k0': [100, 35, 20],
'k1': [2, 0, 40],
'k2': [21, 400, 5],
}

[max(col) for col in zip(*data.values())]
# [100, 400, 40]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use numpy

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.max([*data.values()],axis = 0).tolist()
[100, 400, 40]
```